# css border-radius and background color

Tags: background, css

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
  <img class="in" alt="" src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/---lrEvAvGGs/U2i572OasiI/AAAAAAAACVw/zKSuueH1n5Q/s720/1024x1024.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main{
    height:240px;
    width: 240px;
    background: #F00;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.in {
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
}
```

Live example: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Nzp3/)

As you see in the example, there is a little background color (red) around at the corners of the image.

How to remove these but keeping `border-radius` attribute?

Comment: Why not remove `background: #F00;` from `.main`?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the styles

```
background: #F00; 
border: 1px solid #CCC;
```

from the class `main`.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/3Nzp3/3/

see this fiddle

Remove both line

```
    background: #F00;
    border: 0px solid #CCC;
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove `background: #F00;` and `border: 1px solid #CCC;` from your class main. You will get your output

like

```
.main{
    height:240px;
width: 240px;   
border: 0px;
border-radius: 30px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
    //you can use border: 0px;

}
```

Comment: have you had some look at other answers first? a different time span of about 1 minute between answers is understandable but other answers have been posted 4-5 minutes before.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the code below from the main class

background: #F00;
border: 1px solid #CCC;

i think this will help you .